# When was the first appearance of the abbreviation RSA?

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, computer-science

When was the first publication of the abbreviation RSA (Rivest, Sharmir, Adleman) because it does not appear in Martin Gardner’s article of 1977 which is at the following url:
https://simson.net/ref/1977/Gardner_RSA.pdf

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940941/when-was-the-first-appearance-of-the-abbreviation-rsa

Answer (score 5):

Nor does it appear in [A method for obtaining digital signatures and public-key cryptosystems](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359342) (Communications of the ACM Volume 21 Issue 2, Feb. 1978 Pages 120-126), which was Rivest-Shamir-Adleman's original publication. It is hard to pinpoint the watershed with such obvious abbreviations, but MathSciNet shows [Blakley-Blakley  Security of number-theoretic public key cryptosystems against random attack I](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0161-117891853162) (Cryptologia 2 (1978), no. 4, 306–321) as the earliest occurrence. The trio founding RSA Data Security, Inc. in 1982 (now [RSA Security LLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Security)) probably solidified the usage.